# How To "Endless Document" Script (like Skittles.com)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How did they accomplish this? Have you guys seen: http://www.skittles.com? The site never ends!

Comment: Check this out: [http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/infinite-scroll.html](http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/infinite-scroll.html)

Comment: I've read before that you should be careful when doing this.  I still prefer being able to clicK "next page" instead of having to scroll down towards infinity...  What if your page-viewer refreshes his/her page?  Will the viewer have to scroll down for minutes to get back to the content he/she was at?

Comment: I would recommend **not** doing it. Browsers will get un-happy if you infinitely scroll down. Plus it's somewhat confusing. And what @ItzWary said, if I refresh, I have to start over. That is lame.

Comment: I agree. It's just a cool technique that makes sense for the "Endless Rainbow" of Skittles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's *one* way of doing it:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
     $(window).scroll(
         function(){
             if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
                 $('div').clone().appendTo('body');
             } 
         }
        ); 
    }
    );
```

With the requisite [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/njTWf/).

Bear in mind that any interactive content that's cloned/appended/inserted dynamically will require some kind [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for jQuery to interact with them.

That said, there are caveats:

1. Infinite scrolling isn't necessarily a pleasant navigation aid, particularly if the user is likely to want to view some of the content half way down an infinite page.
2. There comes a point at which a browser will crash or become sluggish/unresponsive due to the sheer volume of content it's required to maintain in memory.